# egit pull new files

Tags: git, egit

I use Eclipse egit to sync with remote git repository. When another user adds a new file to the repository and I do a pull, any new file shows up as a conflict and does not get pulled automatically. Am I missing something that I need to do to get new files?

Comment: need more information, what do you see if you attempt to `git pull` at the command prompt?

Comment: I never tried that until now, and when I did, git showed conflicts with other files in the same directory. I resolved those conflicts and then when I did a pull, the new files were updated. Thanks for the direction! I am still puzzled why I got an egit error window saying I had conflicts in the new files.

Comment: @prusswan: maybe is better idea to use `git pull --rebase`?